# Auto transfer of ETH

Tags: transactions

Is there any way to set up an auto transfer of ETH from one wallet to another when the value hits a certain amount? Eg can I set up a transfer to another wallet to automatically occur ONLY when ETH is at $4000? Thanks in advance. MT

Comment: there is no simple way to do that. you need oracles, a smart contract, and someone/ service to trigger that transaction.